# Why scaffolding not creates ComboBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, scaffolding

I work on my asp.net mvc project.
I create ViewModel and from the view model I create using scaffolding view.

Here is view:

```
public class BookViewModel
{
    public string id { get;set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Add Title")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Author> authors { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Genre> genres { get; set; }

    public BookViewModel()
    {
        this.authors = new List<Author>();
        this.genres = new List<Genre>();
    }
}
```

My action is:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> createBook()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

When view generated only text box for id and title exists.
I expect to see the ComboBox for `authors` and `genres`. But it is empty any idea why it's empty?

Comment: 1. Please show us your view and how you populate it 2. What do you mean with "empty"? Is there no select option in your view or is the select option not filled with values? 3. What you are showing is not your view, but a View Model

Comment: They're collections.  There's a huge number of ways collections can be scaffolded.  Look at [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application#create-a-details-page).  See the first few sentences in that section, then follow that part of the tutorial.

Comment: It might help if you add a `SelectedAuthor` property

Comment: @Marco, there no select option in view

Comment: Please add your action method to the the question as well as your view, so we can help you.

Comment: @Marco please see update